# Add /Remove class and animate

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-animate, addition

I will animate a div with a button. => click . move div top. click again move div bottom . If  i click irt move to top. but if i click again it do nothing.

http://www.kcserver.info/starkk/starkk.at/

click on tv Button

here is my script:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#overlay-tv").animate({top: '0px'}, 4000, 'linear');
        $(this).delay(200).addClass('tv-aktiv');
    });
    $("button.tv-aktiv").click(function(){
        $("#overlay-tv").animate({top: '20px'}, 4000, 'linear');
        $(this).delay(200).removeClass('tv-aktiv');
    });
});
```

Comment: Nothing works in your fiddle!

Comment: give your html to check

Comment: The `delay()` will not delay methods such as non-arguments forms of `show()`, `hide()` and also `addClass()`, `removeClass()` etc. Use `queue()`. Your snippet doesn't work.

Comment: If i insert here it dosen't work. what is the correct js to animate the tv (up and down with button (tv) (see link: http://www.kcserver.info/starkk/starkk.at/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've only registered one click event on your button. 'button.tv-aktiv' does not exist when $(document).ready() fires, therefore jQuery will not find it and append the new click event.

Try this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
          if($(this).hasClass('tv-aktiv') {
            $("#overlay-tv").animate({top: '20px'}, 4000, 'linear');
            $(this).delay(200).removeClass('tv-aktiv');
          } else {
            $("#overlay-tv").animate({top: '0px'}, 4000, 'linear');
            $(this).delay(200).addClass('tv-aktiv');
          } 
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: its possible to add different px values (responsive)

Comment: You could use if($(this).width > 100){}. Although, not the best approach (depends on your use case). Consider using CSS media queries. For example http://codepen.io/timsmiths/pen/WvdVVq